# Merge columns based on value

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 columns, 
I would like to merge the 2 columns with the bigger value into one with the sum. 
Function should throw an error whenever a merge is not possible. (*e.g: when there's a tie on smaller value 0.3,0.3,0.4*)

E.g

```
|A|     |B|     |C|
0.5     0.3     0.2
0.1     0.7     0.2
0.4     0.4     0.2
```

resulting data frame:

```
|X|     |Y|
0.8     0.2  #(x=0.5 + 0.3)
0.9     0.1  #(x=0.7 + 0.2)
0.8     0.2  #(x=0.4 + 0.4)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

***Update:***
*In case someone has the same problem, I used:*

```
apply(dt, 1, function(x) which(x==min(x)))
```

*to find if there are 2 same minimum values in the data frame*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dt$something <- dt$A + dt$B + dt$C - pmin(dt$A,dt$B,dt$C)
```

Your extra condition is easier to handle with a `data.table`

```
dt <- data.table(dt)
dt[,something := A + B + C - pmin(A,B,C) ]
dt[A==B | B ==C | C==A,something := NA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this will get you off to a start:

```
t(apply(mydf, 1, function(x) {a <- sort(x); c(sum(a[2:3]), a[1])}))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  0.8  0.2
# [2,]  0.9  0.1
# [3,]  0.8  0.2
```

You'll need to add your other conditions in though.